# CSS style issue and adding in a graphic

Tags: html, css, image

Two problemss:

1) I am trying to add an icon for FB to this page: http://www.stagecraft.org/msi/#4thpage

No matter whre I add the  reference, the graphic appears at the very bottom of the page, left justified.  I am wanting it to appear center justified just below the text "Jonathan Keith".  What am I missing?

2) On the same site, if you go to the PORTFOLIO page (http://www.stagecraft.org/msi/#3rdPage) and "flip" any card by hovering over it, you will see that the body text appears bold.  If you click the link at the bottom of any of these "cards" you will go to a portfolio subset with the same type of "flipping cards".  However, the body text on the back of these cards is NOT bold.  I am not sure why, as these pages were duplicated from the first.  I would like to have the text bold like the first portfolio level.  What am I missing in the CSS that is resetting this style or preventing it from being bold?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: For your 1st problem, In which `div` are you placing the facebook code?

Comment: I dont see an FB icon there ?

Comment: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for 1 issue use following css

```
#section3 img {
    bottom: -15px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -66px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

for 2 issue your div is placed in side a `<strong>` tag so why text are bold use this css

```
strong .intro .flip p {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

hope this will solve your issue

Comment: #1 fixed.  Thanks.  #2 - not sure why I need to add more CSS when the bold is correct on the first level.  If it applying to those cards why isn't it applying to the other cards as they all share the same CSS style sheet?

Comment: if you check you html code you will find that div id="section2" is wrap with <strong> tag in front page which is not in inside portfolio page, so why fonts are bold in front page.

Comment: OK - but that is reversed.  I WANT all the cards to be <strong>.  What you have knocks the top level cards back to normal.  What do I need to do to get the others back to <strong>?

Comment: Aha - found where I needed to make the BOLD in the existing CSS to do what I want!

Answer (score 0):

For your second problem, Do this :-

```
.flip div:first-child p{
    font-weight: normal!important;
}
```